# How to diagnose & fix disk failing to unmount properly at shutdown?

Tags: boot, unmount

My Ubuntu is consistently failing to properly unmount the disk when shutting down, which means that I have to boot twice each time (I don't reboot often, but it is an issue nonetheless). I've got no idea why did it start doing this - how can I diagnose why is it doing this?

Comment: What version of ubuntu are you using and, if you can, provide a log of what dmesg says about it. Did you edit some file like fstab?

Comment: Why do you think it is not being unmounted properly?  Also what filesystem are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.10. I don't believe fstab has been edited. Here are dmesg files: http://ge.tt/5RKdtJ4. Using ext4, and I know it's being unmounted properly because os-prober on natty failed to detect this partition, and the cause was because it was not unmounted properly - once I mounted and unmounted it in natty, os-prober located it.

Comment: @Vadi is this still affecting you? If yes, can you please paste your linked dmesg files into the question? Also, can you confirm you are really on 10.10 (not 10.04-LTS or 11.10?). Thanks.

Comment: It's been nearly a year since I asked the question... I'm on 11.10 now. I think it's fine now - that, or I have more pressing issues like Ubuntu hibernating right away whenever I unplug my laptop, even though I'm on full battery: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/838543